# Background color full width of page?

Tags: html, css, background

Hello I am trying to figure out how to have the background-Color say on a paragraph or h1 to just be behind the words not stretch across the page with no writing in it?
I’m sorry I am still only learning code I am trying to make a website for my friend and just want it to be right!

Thank you
☺️

Comment: Please put your code into your question - enough for us to be able to see an example of the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Isn't there any content ? If you want to add background color to every word then you have to use `<span class="word_color">Word</span>` and then you can add backgroud color to every word with word_color

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the `background-color` stretches to full width is because `<h1>`-elements are [block-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Block-elements will try to take up the full remaining width, relative to its parent - so if the parent is already taking up the full width of the page, so will the `<h1>`. E.g. see the third example where the `<h1>`-container has `max-width: 50%`, where the `<h1>`-element takes up all that remaining width.

There are several ways to achieve this - in my personal opinion, I think `width: fit-content` is the best solution here, as this will set the `<h1>`-elements width equal to the content inside it. [This doesn't have full browser support though](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content), but is supported in all major browsers (make sure to use the Firefox prefix)

```css
h1 {
  background-color: limegreen;
}

.fit-content {
  width: fit-content;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

div {
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>standard h1</h1>
<h1 class="fit-content">fit-content</h1>
<h1 class="inline-block">inline-block</h1>

<div>
  <h1 class="with-parent">with parent</h1>
</div>
```